# How to generate tables using arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    int k,i,j,n;

    printf("Generate tables upto:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int tables[n][10];
    printf("Table\t");
    for(k=1;k<=10;k++)
    {
        printf("%dx\t",k);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            tables[i][j]=i*j;
            printf("%d\t",tables[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code which i am working on but unfortunately I am not able to generate it the way I want.
The required output should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUL1K.png).

Comment: C arrays start at 0 you know.

Comment: Also, if you get a SegFault (which you will from running this code) try using `gdb` or `valgrind` to figure out why.

Comment: ... with `tables[i][j] = i*j;` being *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane How is `tables[i][j] = i*j` UB? If it were properly indexed it would be fine.

Comment: @EliSadoff because it is not properly indexed. The loop goes to `10`. You cannot index an array of length `10` by `10`, but the multiplier still needs to be `10`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Oh I thought you were saying that `tables[i][j] = i*j` was itself UB even if properly indexed.

Comment: @EliSadoff sigh... I was talking about the code posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proposal fix for your code

- C-arrays start at 0
- you're missing tabs and linefeed at the proper locations

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("color f0");
    int k,i,j,n;

    printf("Generate tables upto:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int tables[n][10];
    printf("Table\t");
    for(k=1;k<=10;k++)
    {
        printf("%dx\t",k);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",i);
        for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            tables[i-1][j-1]=i*j;
            printf("%d\t",tables[i-1][j-1]);
        }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

display with `n=4`

```
Generate tables upto:4
Table   1x      2x      3x      4x      5x      6x      7x      8x      9x      10x
2       2       4       6       8       10      12      14      16      18      20
3       3       6       9       12      15      18      21      24      27      30
4       4       8       12      16      20      24      28      32      36      40
```

Comment: Just one little thing that i am stuck with i want the table for which the output is coming i want that table to be written under table. I am a beginner please bear with me

Comment: I'd gladly help you but [edit] your question to show how the output should be formatted because your explanation is unclear.

Comment: i have accepted your answer now i am looking for your help

Comment: @P.P. I was just saying: I already over-answered and the formerly accepted answer doesn't tackle the formatting problem at all. Check all other questions around: I gladly help with comments on a lot of questions (including that one, earlier than your answer), I don't need acceptance on my comments...

Comment: @SaneeReimoo please show how it should be formatted in the question so the question/answer is coherent. "i want the table for which the output is coming i want that table to be written under table" makes no sense to me.

Comment: there is a hyperlink saying this is what i want in my question please look at it

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing starts from `0` and goes up to `n-1`. So you are accessing out of bounds which is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So you need to rewrite the loops as:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
   for(j=0; j < 10; j++) {
      tables[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
      printf("%d\t", tables[i][j]);
   }
}
```